# InvalidOperationException error in cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, invalidoperationexception

MVC Application in C#.

A Partial View Displays a dropdown and an "Okay" button.  The dropdown displays a list of allowable "Routers" (persons who can route documents in the application).  The user can select a person from the dropdown and then have them made the "Router" by clicking the "Okay" button. The code correctly changes the persons designated as router, but the `error InvalidOperationException` is generated every time the "OKay" button is clicked. The error description is "There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'RouterElect'."

Part of screenshot:

[image]

The code:

```
    @model JudicialPortal.ViewModels.PortalIndexView

<div class="tile">
    Change Current Router
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.RouterElect, Model.JPortalChamberUsersAsItems, new { @id = "changeCurrentRouterInput", @class = "m-wrap", @onchange = "" })
    <button type="button" class="m-btn green-stripe" onclick="changeCurrentRouter();"
        style="color: #444; text-decoration: none;">
        Okay</button>
</div>
```

Router Elect is defined in the ViewModel referenced at the top of the code (PortalIndexView):

```
public string RouterElect { get; set; }
```

The partial view is called from another cshtml page:

```
<div id="ChangeRouterSection" class="live-tile" data-mode="carousel" data-direction="vertical" data-delay="7000">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_ChangeCurrentRouter");}
</div>
```

Comment: When you render the partial do you pass the Model to it, or is it available on the parent page?

Comment: Assuming the @Model statement is "passing the model", it is passed in the partial and also in the parent page.

Comment: Looks like based on the last block of code you are not passing anything as the model to the partial view call the `RenderPartial` function like this `@Html.RenderPartial("_ChangeCurrentRouter", SomeViewModel)`